# Populate the value of an input field with $_FILES['field']['name'];

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, input, upload

I need to retrieve in an Array the value of an upload input field, let me explain :

I have these inputs fields :

```
<input type='text' name='field["+ j++ +"]' value='' data-kind='title' />
<input type='file' name='field["+ j++ +"]' value='' data-kind='image' />
<input type='text' name='field["+ j++ +"]' value='' data-kind='title' />
<input type='file' name='field["+ j++ +"]' value='' data-kind='image' />
```

I print_r the field array from those fields and get that :

```
Array
(
    [0] => title 1
    [2] => title 2
)
```

instead of :

```
Array
(
    [0] => title 1
    [1] => image1.jpg
    [2] => title 2
    [3] => image2.jpg
)
```

I need to have my filenames in my array, how can I have this second array?

I've tried a merge but **I need to preserve the place of each fields in the array like the order of each input in the form** (example : if the upload field is generated at the first place of the form I need to keep that information in the Array ([0] => image1.jpg [1] => title1 and so on)

Any would help would be very very appreciated!! I'm stuck since few days on that :(

Answer (score 0):

If you give inputs the same name, they will simply overwrite each other when they are submitted.  Right now all your inputs are named `field["+ j++ +"]`.

It sounds like you are generating your input tags, so why not just generate a multi-dimensional array to keep the order you want?  Something like this:

```
<input type='text' name='field["+ j++ +"][0]' value='' data-kind='title' />
<input type='file' name='field["+ j++ +"][1]' value='' data-kind='image' />
<input type='text' name='field["+ j++ +"][2]' value='' data-kind='title' />
<input type='file' name='field["+ j++ +"][3]' value='' data-kind='image' />
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I can't do this way because the order is dynamic, when I drag and drop input element it has a specific position which is stored in another array after the submit.

Answer (score 0):

Just give them separate names, then reference them when you loop through your $_FILE/$_POST elements.

```
<input type='text' name='title[]' value='' data-kind='title' />
<input type='file' name='imgfile[]' value='' data-kind='image' />
<input type='text' name='title[]' value='' data-kind='title' />
<input type='file' name='imgfile[]' value='' data-kind='image' />
```

Then in your PHP

```
foreach($_FILES['imgfile']['name'] as $key=>$val){
    echo($key." = ".$val."<br>");
    echo($key." = ".$_POST["title"][$key]."<br><br>");
}
```

Comment: .$_POST["imgfile"] is $_FILES['imgfile'] ? It don't work : "indefined index for 0 and so on"

Comment: The $_POST loop was an example. I've revised the example to use $_FILES.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you've tried [`array_merge`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/array_merge) which will change keys if they are numeric. Instead you can make use of the [array union operator `+`<sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php) which works well with numbered keys and does not change them:

```
$field = 'field';
$fields = $_POST[$field] + $_FILES[$field]['name'];
ksort($fields);
```

This will get you what you're looking for. [Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/RJxeax).